# Cant understand my java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent

Tags: serialization, applet, serialversionuid, appletviewer

I am using serialization to communicate with my server. This way My applet retrieves a `JTree` created in the server. In eclipse and appletViewer my applet works perfectly but when I try to launch my applet from my server I got this error on my console

> java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent; local class
>   incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5858390075012080263,
>   local class serialVersionUID = -1030230214076481435

I tried to get serialVersionUID for every class of my project with `serialver` but none of them have  `serialVersionUID = 5858390075012080263`.

the error is occuring when I try to deserialize my object .
In addition to this ,the error says

> `java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.JComponent`.

How to determine the `JComponent` that causes this error? Is it my `JTree`? How can I set the serialVersionUID? By creating a class that extends this JComponent and set the serialVersionUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I have 4 different JREs on my system. It was a problem with the JVM itself not my classes. Now I use the same JRE everywhere and everything works fine .

Comment: do u remember how you resolved this? I'm having the same problem on Eclipse for Ubuntu